# Windows 7 error_ Socket.Errno: [107] Trasnport end point is not connected

Tags: python, sockets

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS operating on virtual box that is hosted on Windows 7 server computer. I'm running a coupled simulation that needs coupling between two different softwares (OpenFOAM and PFC3D). Here are my client and server codes:

Client:

```
from itasca import p2pLinkClient
import numpy as np
from pyDemFoam import pyDemIcoFoam

solver = pyDemIcoFoam()

with p2pLinkClient() as pfc_link:
    pfc_link.connect("10.0.2.2")

    pfc_link.send_data(solver.nodes())
    pfc_link.send_data(solver.elements())
    pfc_link.send_data(solver.rho())
    pfc_link.send_data(solver.mu())

    while True:
        print "waiting for run time"
        deltat = pfc_link.read_data()
        if deltat == 0.0:
            print "solve finished"
            break
        print "got run time", deltat
        solver.n(pfc_link.read_data())
        solver.f(pfc_link.read_data())
        print "got runtime and data"

        solver.set_dt(deltat)
        solver.solve(deltat)

        print "sending data to pfc"
        pfc_link.send_data(solver.p()*solver.rho())
        pfc_link.send_data(solver.gradp()*solver.rho())
        pfc_link.send_data(solver.U())
        print "send finished"
```

Server:

```
import itasca as it
from itasca import cfdarray as ca
from itasca.util import p2pLinkServer

import numpy as np

with p2pLinkServer() as cfd_link:
    cfd_link.start()

    nodes = cfd_link.read_data()
    elements = cfd_link.read_data()
    fluid_density = cfd_link.read_data()
    fluid_viscosity = cfd_link.read_data()
    print fluid_density, fluid_viscosity
    nmin, nmax = np.amin(nodes,axis=0), np.amax(nodes,axis=0)
    diag = np.linalg.norm(nmin-nmax)
    dmin, dmax = nmin -0.1*diag, nmax+0.1*diag
    print dmin, dmax

    it.command("""
    new
    domain extent {} {} {} {} {} {}
    """.format(dmin[0], dmax[0],
               dmin[1], dmax[1],
               dmin[2], dmax[2]))
    ca.create_mesh(nodes, elements)
    it.command("""
    config cfd
    set timestep max 1e-5
    element cfd ini density {}
    element cfd ini visc {}
    cfd porosity poly
    cfd buoy on
    ball create rad 0.005 x 0.5 y 0.5 z 0.5
    ball ini dens 2500
    ball prop kn 1e2 ks 1e2 fric 0.25
    set gravity 0 0 -9.81
    def fluid_time
      global fluid_time = mech.age
    end
    ball history id 1 zvelocity id 1
    history add id 2 fish @fluid_time
    plot clear
    plot add hist 1 vs 2
    plot add cfdelement shape arrow colorby vectorattribute "velocity"
    """.format(fluid_density, fluid_viscosity))

    element_volume = ca.volume()
    dt = 0.005

    for i in range(100):
        it.command("solve age {}".format(it.mech_age()+dt))
        print "sending solve time"
        cfd_link.send_data(dt) # solve interval
        cfd_link.send_data(ca.porosity())
        cfd_link.send_data((ca.drag().T/element_volume).T/fluid_density)
        print " cfd solve started"
        ca.set_pressure(cfd_link.read_data())
        ca.set_pressure_gradient(cfd_link.read_data())
        ca.set_velocity(cfd_link.read_data())
        print " cfd solve ended"

    cfd_link.send_data(0.0) # solve interval


    print "ball z velocity", it.ball.find(1).vel_z()
```

I ran into the error: Socket.Errno: [107] Trasnport end point is not connected, when I started the coupled calculations. This question was posted and solved for MAC operating system but not windows. I tried the MAC solution but it didn't help. Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? Is it on the client or server side? What solution was proposed for a Mac but not working on Windows? Have you verified that there are not firewalls or other software interfering with traffic between the two systems, and that the IP address of the server is correct?

Answer (score -1):

In the client side of python code, ip address is not allowing to connect. I have tried the same example but in Host-Ubuntu, Guest-Windows combination. By creating static ip for virtualbox I solved the problem. 
Use that in `pfc_link.connect("Static Ip of VBox")` on client side of code.